# How to set the UINavigationItem's backBarButtonItem with an appearance proxy?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I want to set the backBarButtonItem to a custom image for every single navigationBar in my application.

The problem is... you need to set the .backBarButtonItem property on the UINavigationItem. UINavigationItem does not have an appearance proxy. UINavigationBar does, but that doesn't appear to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:backgroundImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```